# Identity Theorem for Complex Analytic Functions, "Disk Version"

Tags: complex-analysis

Before going further, please note:

***I'm quite familiar with the identity theorem for analytic function and the version of the proof using the fact that zeroes of an analytic functions are isolated.***

I'm a bit puzzled by the following exercise from Boas, "Invitation to Complex Analysis":

> Exercise 2.9 Show that if $f$ is analytic and $f'$ is continuous in a region $D$, and the range of $f$ is real, then $f$ is constant in $D$. Hence show that if $f\equiv 0$ in a disk in $D$, then $f\equiv 0$ throughout $D$.

Note: "Region" means non-empty open connected set.

The first part of the exercise is easy: We have $v\equiv0$ and the CR-equations forces $u\equiv C$.

But how does this imply second part of the problem? (i.e. the disk version of the identity theorem?)

Comment: Well, if $f$ is identically zero on a disk in $D$, then are the zeros of $f$ isolated in $D$?

Comment: The conditions of the exercise look a little odd to me: if $\;f\;$ is analytic in a region then it is infinitely differentiable there so *all* its derivatives are analytic as well. Why "to require" $\;f'\;$ is continuous there?

Comment: @Timbuc This exercise is from an earlier part of the book.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon Of course not. Like I said, I'm familiar with the fact that a non-zero analytic $f$ has isolated zeros. I'm curious about the Exercise 2.9, which seems to say that the second part of the problem follows from the first.